# ElasticsearchInstanceCount parameter for AWS Amplify is not updating my elasticsearch domain

Tags: aws-amplify, aws-elasticsearch

I'm trying to set my elasticsearch instance count to `2` but for some reason it's not updating.

I followed this docs: https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/cli-toolchain/graphql#elasticsearchinstancecount

This is my `parameters.json`:

```
{
    "AppSyncApiName": "test",
    "DynamoDBBillingMode": "PAY_PER_REQUEST",
    "DynamoDBEnableServerSideEncryption": "false",
    "APIKeyExpirationEpoch": "0",
    "ElasticsearchInstanceCount": 2,
    "ElasticsearchInstanceType": "t2.medium.elasticsearch"
}
```

However, when `amplify push` has finished, the node count is still `1` and the instance type is still `small`.

Note: I was not using those parameters when I first created the API (which is months ago). However, I also created another env but still the same unfortunately :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I raised a ticket to AWS support and they said it's because it should've been `ElasticSearchInstanceCount` and `ElasticSearchInstanceType` (notice the capital `S` in `ElasticSearch`)